# HTML two-level accordion menu hiding and not adding content

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I'm trying to do a two level accordion menu. The first level works fine but when I add the second level, the second level content hiddes in the first level Section 2 title. Someone knows how can I solve this?

My html code is this :

```
<div class="container-wrapper"></div>
    <button class="accordion"><p class="title-sections">Provisioning</p></button>
    <div class="panel">
        <button class="sub-accordion">Set Variables</button>
        <div class="sub-panel">
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
        <button class="sub-accordion">Get Variables</button>
        <div class="sub-panel">
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
         </div>
         <button class="sub-accordion">Reset</button>
         <div class="sub-panel">
             <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
         </div>
         <button class="sub-accordion">Get Base Report</button>
         <div class="sub-panel">
             <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
         </div>
         </div>
    
     <button class="accordion"><p class="title-sections">Availability</p></button>
     <div class="panel">
         <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
     </div>
```

My CSS :

```
.accordion {
        background-color: #eee;
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

    .sub-accordion {
        background-color: rgb(181, 255, 191);
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

    .active, .accordion:hover {
       background-color: #ccc;
    }

    .sub-active, .sub-accordion:hover {
        background-color: rgb(104, 255, 124);;
    }

    .panel {
      padding: 0 18px;
      background-color: white;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }

    .sub-panel {
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: lightblue;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transform: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }

    .container-wrapper {
        padding: 20pt;
    }

    .title-sections {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
```

And finally my JS, here is the problem. I copy pasted the same code of the first level accordion to make the second level accordion and there's a problem with the height but I don't quite know which part needs to be changed :

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
var sub_acc = document.getElementsByClassName("sub-accordion");
var j;


for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}

for (j = 0; j < sub_acc.length; j++) {
  sub_acc[j].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("sub-active");
    var sub_panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (sub_panel.style.maxHeight) {
      sub_panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      sub_panel.style.maxHeight = sub_panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Am I understing this right. You want to show the second accordion and hide the first accordion when you click it? or you want the first accordion to stay open when the second one opens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fix in Javascript. The solution is just looking for the active accordion and setting its max height again in sub-accordion click logic

```
const activeAccordion = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion active")[0]
var panel = activeAccordion.nextElementSibling;
panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
```

Fully integrated with your Javascript

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
var sub_acc = document.getElementsByClassName("sub-accordion");
var j;


for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}

for (j = 0; j < sub_acc.length; j++) {
  sub_acc[j].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("sub-active");
    var sub_panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (sub_panel.style.maxHeight) {
      sub_panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      sub_panel.style.maxHeight = sub_panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }

    //The change is here
    const activeAccordion = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion active")[0]
    var panel = activeAccordion.nextElementSibling;
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.sub-accordion {
  background-color: rgb(181, 255, 191);
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.sub-active,
.sub-accordion:hover {
  background-color: rgb(104, 255, 124);
  ;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.sub-panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.container-wrapper {
  padding: 20pt;
}

.title-sections {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-wrapper"></div>
<button class="accordion"><p class="title-sections">Provisioning</p></button>
<div class="panel">
  <button class="sub-accordion">Set Variables</button>
  <div class="sub-panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
  <button class="sub-accordion">Get Variables</button>
  <div class="sub-panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
  <button class="sub-accordion">Reset</button>
  <div class="sub-panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
  <button class="sub-accordion">Get Base Report</button>
  <div class="sub-panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="accordion"><p class="title-sections">Availability</p></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Your HTML you need to wrap the whole thing in container-wrapper here's the code for it:

```
<div class="container-wrapper">
  <button class="accordion">
    <p class="title-sections">Provisioning</p>
  </button>
  <div class="panel">
    <button class="sub-accordion">Set Variables</button>
    <div class="sub-panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="sub-accordion">Get Variables</button>
    <div class="sub-panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="sub-accordion">Reset</button>
    <div class="sub-panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="sub-accordion">Get Base Report</button>
    <div class="sub-panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">
    <p class="title-sections">Availability</p>
  </button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and for your CSS:

```
.container-wrapper {
  padding: 20pt;
  //add these two lines
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
}
```